# Extract all numbers in string to array

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have a string like this

```
+3.15% price per day(+63.00% price at day 20)
```

and I want to be able to export it into an array so it becomes something like this

```
{3.15 , 63.00, 20}
```

Can someone help me with this? I'm really stuck at this right now, as I'm not 100% sure how to approach it :\ The reason why I want to do this is because I want to multiple the numbers inside that string by a number like 4, so the result will become

```
+12.60% price per day(+252.00% price at day 20)
```

Here are all the possible cases

```
-3.15% price per day(-63.00% price at day 20)

=>  -12.60% price per day(-252.00% price at day 20)

+0.76 price per day(+15.20 price at day 20)

=>  +3.04 price per day(+60.80 price at day 20)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked at methods such as `Int.TryParse` and `Double.TryParse`? If not, then do!

Comment: this question has nothing to do with "Extract all numbers in string to array"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// export numbers
string input = "+3% price per day(+60% price at day 20)";
int[] array = Regex.Matches(input, @"\d+").OfType<Match>().Select(e => int.Parse(e.Value)).ToArray();

// replace numbers
double k = 3;
string replaced = Regex.Replace(input, @"\d+", e => (int.Parse(e.Value) * k).ToString());

// replace only percents
k = 4;
string replacedPercents = Regex.Replace(input, @"(\d+)%", e => (int.Parse(e.Groups[1].Value) * k).ToString() + "%");

// floating conversion
input = "+0.87 price per day(+63.00 price at day 20)";
string replacedFloating = Regex.Replace(input, @"\+(\d+\.(\d+)|\d+)", e => "+" + (double.Parse(e.Groups[1].Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) * k).ToString(e.Groups[2].Length == 0 ? "0" : "0." + new string('0', e.Groups[2].Length), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

// floating conversion with negatives
input = "-0.87 price per day(+63.00 price at day 20)";
string replacedFloatingNegative = Regex.Replace(input, @"([+-])(\d+\.(\d+)|\d+)", e => e.Groups[1].Value + (double.Parse(e.Groups[2].Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) * k).ToString(e.Groups[3].Length == 0 ? "0" : "0." + new string('0', e.Groups[3].Length), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

**replaced** is

```
+9% price per day(+180% price at day 60)
```

**replacedPercents** is

```
+12% price per day(+240% price at day 20)
```

**replacedFloating** is

```
+12.60 price per day(+252.00 price at day 20)
```

**replacedFloatingNegative** is

```
-3.48 price per day(+252.00 price at day 20)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That's almost perfect. the problem with this is that the numbers sometimes have decimals, and somehow that messes up the final numbers. For example, if it's 0.87, after you multiply it by 4 it should be 3.48, so "+3.48 price per day(+69.60 price at day 20)". Do you think you can help me with this last part? Right now what it returns is 0.348 for some reason :\

Comment: for `"+0.87 price per day(+63.00 price at day 20)"` result is `"+3.48 price per day(+252.00 price at day 20)"` (in last version of my code)

Comment: Thank you, what if I need to do replacedPercentsFloating? the replacedFloating is working 100% now. The percent floating will most likely have -XX.XX% instead of +XX.XX%

Comment: Thank you so much!!! The last thing is that when I try to run it, it says this error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll. Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: what is input string throws exception?

Comment: It just highlights the "e.Groups[1].Value + (double.Parse(e.Groups[2].Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) * k).ToString(e.Groups[2].Length == 0 ? "0" : "0." + new string('0', e.Groups[3].Length), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));" section of the code

Comment: yes, replace ToString(e.Groups[2].Length == 0 with ToString(e.Groups[**3**].Length == 0

Comment: Thanks. Something I noticed is that for 1 of the inputs, it's -0.09% per day (-1.67% at day 18). The multiplier I have is 6 for this, which means it should be -0.54% per day (-9.72% at day 18). However, the code returns -10.02% at day 18 instead of -9.72%. Do you have any idea why it would do this? Is it a sig fig problem?

Comment: Why? 1.67 * 6 = 10.02

Comment: Oh I just realized that the number 1.67 is wrong. The number is pulled from an outside source, which is wrong. 0.09 x 18 = 1.62, not 1.67. That's why the numbers seem different for me. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Just as a last question. If, for example, I have an array containing multiple strings, like the ones above, but some are similar. IE, one string is "+0.76 price per day(+15.20 price at day 20)", another one is "+0.80 price per day(+16.00 price at day 20)" (not sequential). How much work would it take to combine those, 2, so instead of 2 for price, it'd be "+1.56 price per day(+31.20 price at day 20)"?

Comment: It's more complex task that cannot be solved only with regulars.